# how to create a camera like the one in facebook messenger for android

Tags: cordova, camera, cordova-plugins

The facebook messenger in android has an inbuilt camera which also has edit feature with free hand drawing and annotations. 
Is there any other opensource libraries or plugins for making such a camera with cordova?

Comment: did you find any resources?

Comment: @vzhen no , i ended up in using http://leimi.github.io/drawingboard.js/ for editing images after saving from camera